# Check the state of a checkbox in c#

Tags: c#, checkbox, windows-phone

I'm creating an app for Windows Phone and I need to check the state of a `CheckBox` this is what I have atm;

```
if (tracking.Checked)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Checked");
}
```

But the word "Checked" in the if statement is underlined in red. I have also tried

```
if (tracking != null) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Checked");
}
```

any advice/ideas on where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: _if statement is underlined in red_ What red line says as a tooltip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use property **IsChecked**.

**xaml**:

```
        <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox" />
```

**cs**:

```
        if (CheckBox.IsChecked == true)
        {}
        else
        {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned Windows Phone, I assume you're using WPF. It looks like you need to use the "IsChecked" property (WinForms had "Checked").

```
if (tracking.IsChecked)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Checked");
}
```